# Looking sorted order for Springs dropdown back

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-webflow

I am losting soft order of my list as I convert to Map.. How else can I do this... Spring needs my list as a Map for my dropbox

```
Map<String, String> selectableReporters = new HashMap<String, String>();
List<NameID_lookupModel> lstReports = database.getSelectableReporters();

for (NameID_lookupModel i : lstReports) selectableReporters.put(i.getID(), i.getName() + " - " + i.getID());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LinkedHashMap` instead `HashMap` may help if the content is already sorted and in the order you want to display. `LinkedHashMap` keeps insertion order.

```
LinkedHashMap<String, String> insertionOrderMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
```

If your list is already sorted, Iterate over list and add to LinkedHashMap

Add list items to above map.

Comment: can you please give me a sample on how to do the above

Comment: Thank you! By the way I learned from SO community, used at my work and now I contributed. So, SO community is best.